# Which way is correct for timeout $_SESSION

Tags: php

I am currently stuck with my session and the way to include them in a if statement for a timeout code.

Which would be correct?:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['time']) && $_SESSION['time'] < (time() - 3600)) {
  session_unset();
  session_destroy();
  include(__DIR__ . '/home.php');
  exit;
}
```

or

```
if (isset($_SESSION['time']) < (time() - 3600)) {
  session_unset();
  session_destroy();
  include(__DIR__ . '/home.php'); 
  exit;
}
```

Comment: The first one is correct.  In the second, doing `isset($_SESSION['time'])` returns boolean `true/false` which gets cast to a number `1/0` if you try to use it directly with `< (time() - 3600)` and so it is evaluated as `1 < (time() - 3600)` which is going to be `true` whether 1 or 0.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski ok thank you

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski You're correct that the second one is incorrect, but `true < ANY_NUMBER` will always evaluate to false, not true. If `isset($_SESSION['time'])` were cast to an int then the condition would be true for any number greater than one, but there is no cast.

Comment: @mtinsley Indeed - I don't find explicit examples, but [`<,>` result in strict comparisons](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) so they're not cast.